# Why is template not registered?

Tags: templates, xslt

I am trying to add a template to an existing docbook system, and I don't understand how the whole thing works.  I figured out how to add verbose logging so my simple addition now generates about 250000 lines of log output.  I know the syntax is correct, but the template is not added to the rest of the system.

Here is the included code:

```html
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- **********************************************************************

     ********************************************************************** -->

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
                version='1.0'>


<xsl:template name="mike2">
 Add this text
</xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="mike">
  <xsl:call-template name="mike2">
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is what I see in the log:

```html
[xsltproc] xsltCompilePattern : parsing 'mike'
 [xsltproc] xsltCompilePattern : parsed mike, default priority 0.000000
 [xsltproc] added pattern : 'mike' priority 0.000000
 [xsltproc] parsed 2 templates
 [xsltproc] parsed 0 templates
 [xsltproc] Resolving attribute sets references
 [xsltproc] Creating sub-dictionary from stylesheet for transformation
 [xsltproc] Registered 0 modules
:
:
 [xsltproc] Element mike in namespace 'http://docbook.org/ns/docbook' encountered in chapter, but no template matches.
```

The log shows the templates are parsed, so the syntax is ok, but then it says "Registered 0 modules", and when it sees the tag  in the *.xml file, it then says "no template matches".  WHY?

Thanks.
Edit:
xml source:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE chapter [
<!ENTITY % local_ents SYSTEM "file:///local/entities.ent">
<!ENTITY % product_ents SYSTEM "file:///product/entities.ent">
<!ENTITY % common_ents SYSTEM "file:///common/entities.ent">
<!ENTITY % global_ents SYSTEM "file:///global/entities.ent">
%local_ents;
%product_ents;
%common_ents;
%global_ents;
]>


<chapter xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" version="5.0-extension xes-1.0"
  xml:id="Memory">

  <title>Memory</title>
<mike/>
  <para>  This is the

    <emphasis role="red" >&check; &agr; &aacgr;</emphasis>
  </para>

  <para><emphasis role="green">memory section of the report. &check;</emphasis>
</para>


</chapter>
```

Comment: We could give you an intelligent answer if we could see your XML input. However, the last line of your log says that the element `mike` is in a *namespace* - so your template will not match it. Try perhaps: `<xsl:template match="db:mike">`?

Comment: The xml input is trivial: <mike/>  I tried the db:mike, it gives :xsltCompilePattern : parsing 'db:mike' with same result.  But the thing I should try is to ensure _all_ the name spaces are listed in the xml file.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and provide a [mcve]. And I believe reading up on default namespaces and how they are inherited could help your understanding.

Comment: No problem with moving the code.  It looks like the docbook name space is common, so if the template is defined under that name space, and then used in that name space, it should work.  But xsltproc reports it is not registered.  What does it take to be added to the name space?

Comment: I don't know in which environment you're working. In XSLT, no namespace is "common". If you want to match the `mike` element, you must define a prefix bound  to the same namespace (your stylesheet already does that) and use that prefix in your template's match pattern. Once you do that, the template *will* be executed and the other template will be called - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamL5 (I have removed the external entity references that cannot be resolved without access to the referenced files).

Comment: I see - my inherited environment is doing something over and beyond what the rules are.  It's not that there is something wrong with the code, my environment is not allowing it.  Thank you for running the test.  I have to dig much deeper into my whole system (which is ridiculously huge).